# Making a dumb memory mistake

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I haven't used C++ in quite a while and I seem to be making what I'm sure is a very stupid mistake.  Could someone tell me why

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
        double* atoms;

        atoms = (double*)malloc(10 * 3*sizeof(double));
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                        atoms[i*10 + j] = 2.0;
                }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                        cout << atoms[i*10 + j] << endl;
                }
                cout << endl;
        }


        free(atoms);

        return 0;
}
```

is printing

```
2
2
2

2
2
2

2
2
2

6.94528e-310
6.94528e-310
0

0
4.24399e-314
4.24399e-314

2
2
2

2
2
2

2
2
2

2
2
2

2
2
2
```

instead of all 2's?  Thanks

Comment: Did you use a debugger? Notice that in the second loop, `i` can be 9, and then you are addressing the element of index 90 which overflows the `malloc`-ed zone.

Comment: Just use `std::vector` of vectors and save yourself the confusion..

Comment: Also, malloc is allowed to return NULL.

Comment: Yeah, I realize I'm violating like 47 good coding conventions, but right now I'm honestly trying to just generate something as quickly as possible (deadline).  The code itself doesn't matter as long as I get a valid output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`malloc(10 * 3*sizeof(double))` allocates enough memory for 30 doubles.

The loop:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    atoms[i*10 + j] = 2.0;
            }
    }
```

accesses well past the last allocated element (which would be `atoms[29]`).  For example, when `i == 3` and `j == 0` you're accessing `atoms[30]`.  Any accesses when `i >= 3` are out of bounds.

Comment: Gah, thanks.  Sorry.  I've been coding the last 12 hours and staring at this the last 20 minutes trying to figure out what silly thing I did wrong.

Answer (score 3):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    atoms[i*10 + j] = 2.0;
```

I guess, you wanted to write:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    atoms[j*10 + i] = 2.0;
```

You have the same mistake in both loops, to be exact, I thought it was obvious :)

Comment: Max i = 9, max j = 2; j * 10 + i = 20 + 9 = 29, what fits into allocated memory, am I missing something?

Comment: Nope, I seem to be slow today..

Answer (score 0):

The error lies inside your cycles (both of them):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
             atoms[i*10 + j] = 2.0;// <-- wrong index computation
      }
}
```

in both of your cycles it should instead be:

```
atoms[i*3 + j] = 2.0;
```

instead. Just output `i*10 + j` each iteration, and you will see your mistake. You are trying to access the elements in this order:

```
0 1 2 10 11 12 20 21 22 30 31 32 40 41 42 50 51 52 60 61 62 70 71 72 80 81 82 90 91 92 2
```